# Symfony error: "EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given"

Tags: php, symfony, object, error-handling, var

I'm new to Symfony, I'm trying to build a little web project, and I met an error on my Symfony interface.

I get this error while I want launch my web project:

> EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.

And here is the related code:

```
    public function homepage(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $productRepository = $em->getRepository(Product::class);

        $product = $productRepository->find(3);

        $em->remove($product);

        $em->flush();

        dd($product);

        return $this->render('home.html.twig');
    }

}
```

How can I fix it?

I tried to change the value setting of the $product, but nothing happens.

Comment: The code is not balanced. Was the last "`}`" intended?